# How to prove $ \int_{\mathbb R^n} [V(\epsilon_i y)- V(0)]\phi_i(y)dy\rightarrow 0 $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Assume $\epsilon_i\rightarrow 0, \phi_i\rightharpoonup\phi_\infty$ in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$, and $||\phi_\infty||_{H^2}=1$, besides $V(x)$ is a continue bounded function, how to show 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} [V(\epsilon_i y)- V(0)]\phi_i(y)dy\rightarrow 0  
$$

What I try: I decompose the $\int_{\mathbb R^n}$ int to $\int_{\mathbb R^n/B_R(0)}$ and $\int_{B_R(0)}$ , where $B_R(0)$ is the R-ball.  But since the $R$ depend on the $i$, so the proof is fail. What should Ido ? Or it is wrong ?

Comment: I fail to see why this integral needs to exist. Do you also assume $\phi_i$ to be in $L^1$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  All $\phi_i$ are in $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: But $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ does not imply $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, or am I mistaken? Consider $n=1$ and a smooth function such that $f(x)=1/x$ outside some ball. This guy is in $H^2$, but not in $L^1$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven   You are right. But I feel $H^2$ maybe is enough, since $\epsilon_i \rightarrow 0$. Do you have a  counter-example   ? Besides, could you give the proof of $\phi_i$ in $L^1$ ? Maybe , it is heuristic .  Thanks.

Comment: It is not enough, pick $\phi_i=\phi$ as above and pick $V(x)=1$ for $\vert x\vert \leq 1$ and $V(x)=1/\vert x \vert$. Then the integral does not exist for any $i$.

Comment: Also, I do not know a proof for this, even if you throw in integrability. Could you explain why you believe this to be true?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven   Do you think $\int [V(\epsilon_i y) - V(0)]\phi dy= \int V(\epsilon_i y)\phi dy - \int V(0)\phi dy$, since only $H^2$ the $\phi$ is belone to, so   $\int V(0)\phi dy$ maybe unbounded.  But you fail to use the $\epsilon_i\rightarrow 0$.  In fact,  I think the integral can't be separated.

Comment: That was not what I was thinking. In my example you have outside of a ball $V(\varepsilon_i x) - V(0) < - \frac{1}{2}$ (if I pick for example V(0)=1). Thus, the integrand outside of a ball is less or equal than $-\frac{1}{2} \phi$, so the integral does not exist. Well, it is actually equal to $-\infty$. So you should really explain what makes you believe in that convergence.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  You are right , I misunderstand you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is simply wrong. Even if we assume in addition $\phi_i\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ it will not be true (we can make them even smooth, in $H^n$ and in any $L^p$ still it wouldn't work). The problem is, that the "mass" of the $\phi_i$ needs not be concentrated on a bounded set. I guess you wanted to exclude this by putting the $H^2$-norm of the limiting function to 1. However, this is not enough.

Let $\phi\in H^2\cap L^1$ and let $f_n(x)=f(x+b_n e_1)$ (where $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector and $b_n\rightarrow \infty$). Now we pick $f$ to be $C^2$ with compact support and set $\phi_n= \phi + f_n$. The $f_n$ clearly converge weakly to the zero function, thus our sequence satisfies all your conditions.

For completeness let me pick $V(x)=\frac{1}{1+\vert x\vert^2}$. I only need a bit of decay at infinity to make it work (note that we can make this potential as nice as we like as long as it decays a bit at infinity, we are in business).

By dominated convergence we have
$$ \int [V(\varepsilon_n y) -V(0)] \phi(y) dy \rightarrow 0. $$
To render your claim true, you would need to have
$$ \int [V(\varepsilon_n y) -V(0)] f_n(y) dy \rightarrow 0, $$
which simply is not true in general.

Assume for example $f\geq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Choose the $b_n$ such that $ V(\varepsilon_n x) - V(0) \leq -\frac{1}{2} V(0)$ for $x\in [-b_n, -b_n +1]$, then 
$$ \int [V(\varepsilon_n y) -V(0)] f_n(y) dy \leq -\frac{1}{2} V(0)$$
And in particular it does not converge to zero.